# combinations to find out the points if the x and y values gives in a list

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

Looking forward to suggestions using itertools

I have two lists of values for X and Y-axis

```
x=[75.0, 75.0, 74.5 ]
y=[34.0, 34.0, 33.5 ]
```

I want to know the  points that I can obtain with these values, Don't need the combinations which starts with Y values and need to avoid the points due to duplicate values in x and y

the output that I am expecting

```
out= [(75,34),(75,33.5),(74.5,34),(74.5,33.5)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

set(product(x,y))
# {(74.5, 33.5), (74.5, 34.0), (75.0, 33.5), (75.0, 34.0)}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `set` to remove duplicates from each candidate list *before* forming the product.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). I would also remove the duplicates from the original lists to avoid getting duplicates in the result.

```
from itertools import product


res = list(product(set(x), set(y)))

print(res)  # -> [(74.5, 33.5), (74.5, 34.0), (75.0, 33.5), (75.0, 34.0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this using set comprehension

```
x=[75.0, 75.0, 74.5 ]
y=[34.0, 34.0, 33.5 ]

out = list({(i, j) for i in x for j in y})
```